# I want to solve my SQL query problem include UNION ALL and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union-all

I wrote this SQL query, but it did not return any results, it throws an error even though the first statement behind union all and front works separately. I think the problem is about order by and union all working together.

What is wrong using them together with? Why SQL does not allow to it? And, how to handle it?

I tried this but it gives following error.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(NAME, '(', LEFT(OCCUPATION,1), ')')
FROM
    OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY 
    NAME ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(OCCUPATION), ' ', LOWER(OCCUPATION), 's.')
FROM
    OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY 
    OCCUPATION
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(OCCUPATION) ASC, OCCUPATION ASC
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL
> SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(OCCUPATION), ' ', LOWER(O' at line 4

Comment: Hi, please describe what is it that you need to achieve, and add some schema to describe the table. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-operations.html#set-operations-order-by-limit

> To apply an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to an individual query block used as part of a union, intersection, or other set operation, parenthesize the query block, placing the clause inside the parentheses, like this:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND b=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND b=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```